# Typescript not understanding that two different types should be equal

Tags: typescript

I simplified this issue into the following function. It seems like a pretty dumb function but I think the problem is easier to look at when dead simple:

```js
function animalTransformer<T,R>(transform? : (animal: T) => R) {
    transform = transform ? transform : (animal : T) => animal
    // ^^^^^^ attempt to set a default function, `transform` underlined with error

    // ... other stuff
}
```

`'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.ts(2322)`

But how is this a problem? I would expect typescript to infer that R must equal T in this circumstance. Is there a way I can tell typescript somehow that if `transform` is not set in the arguments, that that means R = T? I would expect that should be enforced at higher levels of abstraction if there is some sort of type conflict detected rather than at this level?

Can someone explain why this behaviour is happening and also the simplest most elegant way to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: `T` and `R` are chosen by the *caller*.  I could call `animalTransformer<string, number>()` without error, and then the implementation would mistakenly be saying that a `string` will be a `number`, and quite possibly lead to runtime errors.  So, that's why it's happening.  The ways to solve it are mentioned in the linked questions.